# Matching words in uppercase with Regular expression on a text with multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I scraped several articles and collected them in a text file. From these articles I would like to extract all the words written in uppercase:

This is a sample of one of the articles collected:

```
"|[<p>Advertisement ,   By  Milan Schreur  and     Alissa J. Rubin    OCT. 5, 2016 
 ,  BRUSSELS — A man wounded two police officers with a knife in Brussels around noon on Wednesday in what the authorities called “a potential terrorist attack.” , ....]"
```

What I want to extract are all those words typed in caps lock, in this case, the word "BRUSSELS", but in the file there are many more. So I would like to extract all those words entirely made of uppercases.

I tried with something like this:

```
import re 

text_open = open("Training_News_6.csv")
text_read = text_open.read()
articles = text_read.split("<p>")
pattern = re.findall("\s[A-Z]{4,}\s",'\n'.join(articles))
print(pattern)
```

Comment: `re.findall` accepts string or bytes-like object and you passed a list to it!

Comment: `articles` is a list. To pass a string, just join with linefeed again: `pattern = re.findall("[\S\s]+[A-Z]{3,}",'\n'.join(articles)) `

Comment: Also, do you want the world `Alissa J. Rubin` entirely?

Comment: Why the `[\S\s]+`? Note that if you have backslashes like that you would better use  a raw string literal: `r"...."`

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestion. @Kasramvd No, I am just looking for words with 3 or more letters in uppercase

Comment: "BRUSSELS"  is the perfect example of the words I am looking for

Comment: I just solved myself with @Jean-FrançoisFabre 's tip. Shall I close the question?

Comment: Don't mind if you do :)

Answer (score 0):

`articles` is a list, after you did `text_read.split`. `re.findall` is expecting a string.